# Переход PHP 7 - 5 v

Tags: php, sql

Помогите , на старом хосте была версия пхп на сколько я помню 7.0.23 а на новом 5.5.38 , и вроде на старом хосте работала эта штука

```
$GetMail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resch1)['email'];
```

говорит что "[" не понимает , а конкретнее

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in 
<b>/home/trikedgo/domains/sochack.com/public_html/functionsl.php</b> on 
line <b>18</b><br />
```

18 линия это и есть

```
$GetMail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resch1)['email'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Разделите строчку на две

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resch1);
$GetMail = $row['email'];
```

Раньше PHP не умел сразу работать с массивами, которые возвращались из функции